# Wordpress redirect to login page if ip is different

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, redirect, intranet

I am making an intranet site in Wordpress that can be viewed from a specific IP or it redirects to the login page if it is accessed from another IP. I tried to redirect from .htaccess and from functions.php but with no success.
In functionts.php I put this code found in another post:

```
    function ip_based_login() {
    $visitor = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $redirectTo = site_url('wp-admin');

    if (!preg_match("/95.81.51.134/",$visitor)) {
        wp_redirect($redirectTo);
    }

    exit;
}
add_action('init', 'ip_based_login');
```

This code gives me the error: The page isn’t redirecting properly in Firefox.
I deleted the code form .htaccess  before I thought of posting.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please post the relevant parts of your '.htaccess' and 'functions.php' showing what you have tried so far (without any confidential information, of course) so others can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via plugin

Restricted Site Access

It has what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The plugin solved the problem but I am also curious to find out a coding solution.

Comment: Glad it helped..


Try this on .haccess and see whether you are able to do the same via config.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^enter.your.ip.here
RewriteRule .* http://yoururlhere [R=302,L]

Comment: also wordpress forum has the code you are looking for.. 

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/redirect-based-on-location-example-solved/

Comment: I tried via config. and it gives me this error: The page isn’t redirecting properly. I am trying on localhost.